# Meteor 1.3 JavaScript Backend simple-todos-react

Tags: javascript, meteor, backend

I am completely new to Meteor 1.3.
I am trying to test 
https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos-react
on Amazon AWS.

```
   $ ssh -i aws_key_pair.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
   $ cd /var/www/html

   $ meteor create simple-todos

   $ git clone git@github.com:meteor/simple-todos-react.git
   $ meteor npm install
   $ meteor

$ cd /var/www/html/simple-todos/simple-todos-react

   $ ls -lah
total 280K

drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Jun 18 03:14 client

drwxrwxr-x 8 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Jun 18 03:14 .git  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   14 Jun 18 03:14 .gitignore  
drwxrwxr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Jun 18 03:14 imports  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1.2K Jun 18 03:14 LICENSE  
drwxrwxr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Jun 18 04:06 .meteor  
drwxrwxr-x 7 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Jun 18 03:27 node_modules  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  282 Jun 18 03:14 package.json  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  438 Jun 18 03:14 README.md  
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 229K Jun 18 03:14 screenshot.png  
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Jun 18 03:14 server  


   $ meteor update
simple-todos-react: updated to Meteor 1.3.3.1.

   $ meteor

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                                                            

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

When I try to start the app from google chrome browser I get nothing.
http://www.example.com/simple-todos/simple-todos-react/client/main.html

Btw.
http://www.example.com/index.html works.

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you starting the app in Chrome? It should be http://[yourSever'sIP]:3000